# Why is NA^0 = 1 in R?

Tags: r

It is a simple question, but why is `NA^0 = 1` in R?  I didn't realize this until getting surprising results.  Shouldn't this result in NA?  All the other numeric operations applied to NA seem to return NA as expected.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863619/why-does-nan0-1

Comment: Looks like the check for bases of 1 or exponents of 0 happen before the check for NA: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/6d99f42982c486c12f54b937484ad41b8d608bb4/src/main/arithmetic.c#L200

Comment: @MrFlick thanks, should I delete this or leave it as a link to the NaN question?  I didn't think to search NaN.

Comment: It is a slightly different question even if the answer is exactly the same. Might as well leave it up.

Comment: It's also why `1^NA == 1`