# Why is NA^0 in R gives 1 and not NA

Tags: r

I've just encounter a weird behaviour of R which I would like to understand.

When I do `NA^0` it gives 1 and not NA as I would have expected.

example:

```
v1 <- c(2,NA,1)
v1^0
[1] 1 1 1
v1**0
[1] 1 1 1
```

`^` and `**` are arithmetic operators (`help("^")`) like `-`, `+`, etc. which in their case gives NA:

```
v1+0
[1]  2 NA  1
v1-0
[1]  2 NA  1
```

Why are the different operators performe differently with NAs?

Comment: I remember my mathematics teacher saying ***"Anything raise to 0 is 1".***

Comment: This is what it does. This result has been exploited on a number of SO answers to produce vectorized solutions in the presence of NA values.

Comment: You can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863619/why-does-nan0-1

Comment: @Ronak Shah Even a NULL value???  I know the mathematical law for numbers, but from a computer point of view, I would have expected (and prefer) that NULL value stay NULL when raised to 0...

Comment: `NULL^0 = numeric(0)`

Comment: NA is *not* equivalent  to NULL. From the help file `?NA`: "NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator."  and from `?NULL`, "NULL represents the null object in R." These are distinct concepts. Consider a data.frame, df, with variable v1. `df$v1 <- NA` sets the values of the variable to missing, whereas `df$v1 <- NULL` removes the variable.

Comment: After a quick read of the like posted (which I missed in my search, I apologise), I see the point of that behaviour.  Personnaly, I would have prefer the other behaviour to be able to use this operation as a `is.na` alternative.  Anyway, thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close this as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863619/why-does-nan0-1), but since your question seems to be "how can I avoid this behavior and return NA instead":

```
your_exp <- Vectorize(function(base, exp) ifelse(is.na(base),NA,base^exp))
v1 <- c(2,NA,1)

your_exp(v1,0)
# returns [1]  1 NA  1
```

Please see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17865241/2573061) for why `NA^0 == 1`.