# Aggregate only at specific rows with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a data.table that is quite large.  I would like to do some aggregation on only select rows but using all of the data (i.e. not just the select rows).  Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dt = data.table(
    date = seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day")
)

dt$day = day(dt$date)
dt$value = rnorm(nrow(dt))
```

What I would like is to take a 30 day rolling average.  Normally this can be accomplished by the following:

```
library(RcppRoll)
ma30 = dt[, roll_mean(value, 30, fill = NA, align = "right"), by = day]
```

However, in this case I am only concerned with the rolling average when day is equal to 15.  Is there some way to write the above statement such that I can take the average of **all** previous 30 days but only at the 15th of each month?  In other words I want to use 365 data points but only make 12 calculations (or 11 since the first would be `NA` anyway).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

```
# option 1:
dt[, roll_mn := roll_mean(value, 30, fill = NA, align = "right") * NA^(day != 15)]

# option 2:
dt[, roll_mn := ifelse(day == 15, roll_mean(value, 30, fill = NA, align = "right"), NA)]
```

you get:

> ```
> > dt[1:100]
>            date day        value    roll_mn
>   1: 2017-01-01   1 -0.422983983         NA
>   2: 2017-01-02   2 -1.549878162         NA
> ....
>  13: 2017-01-13  13  0.712481269         NA
>  14: 2017-01-14  14 -0.445772094         NA
>  15: 2017-01-15  15  0.248979648         NA
>  16: 2017-01-16  16 -1.074193951         NA
>  17: 2017-01-17  17 -1.827261716         NA
> ....
>  44: 2017-02-13  13  1.054362321         NA
>  45: 2017-02-14  14 -0.148639594         NA
>  46: 2017-02-15  15  1.018076577 -0.1322037
>  47: 2017-02-16  16 -0.721586512         NA
>  48: 2017-02-17  17 -0.778778137         NA
> ....
>  72: 2017-03-13  13  0.565180699         NA
>  73: 2017-03-14  14 -0.006097837         NA
>  74: 2017-03-15  15 -0.438781066  0.1109928
>  75: 2017-03-16  16  0.688891096         NA
>  76: 2017-03-17  17 -0.499419195         NA
> ....
>  99: 2017-04-09   9 -0.657354771         NA
> 100: 2017-04-10  10  0.922903744         NA
> ```

---

A benchmark on a lager dataset (including the non-equi join option mentioned by @Frank in the comments):

```
# create benchmark dataset
set.seed(2018)
dt <- data.table(date = seq.Date(as.Date("0-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day"))
dt[, `:=` (day = day(date), value = rnorm(nrow(dt)))]

# benchmark
> system.time(dt[, v1 := roll_mean(value, 30, fill = NA, align = "right") * NA^(day != 15)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.011   0.000   0.011 
> system.time(dt[, v2 := ifelse(day == 15, roll_mean(value, 30, fill = NA, align = "right"), NA)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.034   0.005   0.039 
> system.time(dt[day == 15, v3 := dt[.SD[, .(d_dn = date - 30, d_up = date)], on=.(date > d_dn, date <= d_up), mean(value), by=.EACHI]$V1])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.043   0.001   0.044
```

*Warning: the non-equi join approach will give also a value for the first row where `day == 15`*

---

Used data:

```
set.seed(2018)
dt <- data.table(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "1 day"))
dt[, `:=` (day = day(date), value = rnorm(nrow(dt)))]
```

Comment: Does this actually compute all of them and then set all the day != 15 to NA?  It looks like it but I have never seen this NA^ usage before.  I am trying to avoid doing unnecessary computations.

Comment: @fsumathguy That's true, added another option.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you.  So simple in hindsight.

Comment: @fsumathguy Although it might feel contradictory, the first option is about 3x faster.

Comment: That is extremely counterintuitive.  How could an if statement be so burdensome?

Comment: Both options compute them all, right? (I guess you know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow ) I think you should consider a non-equi join, perhaps: `dt[day == 15, v := dt[.SD[, .(d_dn = date - 30, d_up = date)], on=.(date > d_dn, date <= d_up), mean(value), by=.EACHI]$V1]` Looking at `dt[c(46, 74)]` I see it matches your values, but haven't benchmarked or anything.

Comment: @fsumathguy An interesting discussion, mostly on `NaN^0`, but also on `NA^0`, can be found here: [Why does NaN^0 == 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863619/why-does-nan0-1)

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` you can use case_when to check if the date is equal to 15 then take the rolling mean.

```
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)
dt %>% mutate(roll_sum = case_when(day == 15 ~ roll_mean(value, 30, align = "right", fill = NA)))
```